# Best way to reposition 5 DIVs with CSS/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I've a cached page (so, i can't modify it) with 5 results. I want to let the user order by "older" or "newer".

So, this would be the html:

```
<div class="result">Result #1</div>
<div class="result">Result #2</div>
<div class="result">Result #3</div>
<div class="result">Result #4</div>
<div class="result">Result #5</div>
```

And I want a way to easily reorder the results so they can be seen like:

```
Result #5
Result #4
Result #3
Result #2
Result #1
```

How could I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sorting to reverse the existing DOM order or are you sorting by the text in each div?

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to reverse not just the text, but the DIVs that contains the results (they have text and other functions inside). Although I don't care the order of the DOM elements, I'm just interested in the order the users sees them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse the order of the `result` divs like this:

```
var items = $(".result");
var parent = items.eq(0).parent();
items.each(function() {
    parent.prepend(this);
});​
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hvGy5/

Comment: @Santiago - It is unclear to me why the original didn't work, but I've modified it to something that does work and included a working demo.

Comment: @Santiago I knew mine had to be slower, but I got curious, so here's for you to see http://jsperf.com/numbering-upsidedown ( Almost by half! :/ )

Answer (score 4):

There is a great plugin that will do that

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/